# Iterate over a dataframe column and remove website prefix and endtags

Tags: python, loops

I have a dataframe of URLs and I want to remove the 'www.' and '.com' out of it. The '.com' might also be '.org', '.net' etc. I was thinking something like the below might work but need some support getting a working script.

```
for i in x: # x = single column dataframe of URLs
  if i.endswith('.com'):
      x = i[:-4]
  if i.startswith('www.'):
      x = i[4:]
x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use `str.replace` with an appropriate regular expression:

```py
df["url"] = df["url"].str.replace(r'^www\.|\.(?:com|org|net)$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all links will have prefixes and suffixes, you can do

```
new_urls = [url.split('.')[1] for url in x]
```

for simple urls.

If you're expecting dots to appear within urls, you can use

```
new_urls = ['.'.join(url.split('.')[1:-1]) for url in x]
```